# Sql Query to get column name from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below code i have a

document table

```
document name   |  document id  |  client id
```

and attachment table

```
attach id   |   document id   |   attachment name.
```

I want to get attachemt name from attachment table.in the below code i get document id,document name ,clientid from document name and i want to get attachment name from attachment table.how to do in this same query.

```
@i_DocumentID varchar(MAX)


SELECT 
    DocumentID, 
    DocumentName,
    ClientID 
FROM Documents  
WHERE DocumentID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_DocumentID))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@i_DocumentID varchar(MAX)   

 SELECT 
    a.DocumentID, 
    a.DocumentName,
    a.ClientID,
    b.AttachmentName
    from Documents  a 
    join Attachments b on a.DocumentId = b.DocumentId

    where a.DocumentID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_DocumentID))
```

You can read more about joins here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp or here http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1667/sql-server-join-example/

Comment: +1 for the nice and structured answer. Try to find a more relevant link, `w3s` is not 100% accurate and the question is flagged as `sql-server`

Answer (score 0):

Use a join:

```
@i_DocumentID varchar(MAX)
SELECT D.DocumentID, D.DocumentName,D.ClientID, A.Attachement_name
from Documents D JOIN
     Attachment A on D.document_id=A.document_id
where D.DocumentID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_DocumentID))
```

Comment: it throw Ambiguous column name 'DocumentID'. in where condition

Comment: Use `where D.DocumentID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_DocumentID))`and it will work. Error appeared cause SQLServer doesn't recognise if he should take DocumentId from table Documents or Attachments, if in two tables you have the columns which are named the same you need to use alias

Comment: @user3492682: Edited my answer. Changed the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need a JOIN.

```
@i_DocumentID varchar(MAX)


SELECT d.DocumentID, DocumentName,ClientID,AttachmentName 
from Documents d
INNER JOIN attachment a 
ON a.document_id=d.document_id 
where DocumentID IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVToTable(@i_DocumentID))
```